# Can't run on Mac after performing Wipe Free Space Only

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

These are the steps:

1. I installed Windows bootcamp on my MacBook;
2. I used CCleaner to Wipe Free Space Only on my Hard Drive

Result: I can't start the MacBook on Mac-system, the system immediatelly chooses Windows as OS.

Comment: press `alt` at startup and you should be able to choose the booting OS

Comment: Already tried alt many times, but I might fix it with TestDisk

Comment: Can you open the disk manager on windows and tell us the number of partition(s) you have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hold command-R on startup, open Disk Utility, and repair both the OS X volume (indented below the whole disk) and the whole disk. The Repair Disk button performs different actions depending on whether a whole disk or a volume is selected.

If you still cannot start up in OS X, you can try to [reinstall OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13871) by starting up from the recovery partition and selecting Reinstall OS X. It installs a new copy of OS X over the current installation but keeps your files and settings in place.

If you don't already have backups, you can save a disk image of the OS X volume from Disk Utility. See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1553.